# App Redirecting

Tags: android, ios

i'm looking to create an app for IOS & Android. Now, its very early days and I'm no tech whizz, so I thought i'd put it to you wonderful people for some advice. Basically, I need to know if its possible, or there is at least a way of getting around, redirecting from one app to another. Re-directing from an app to a mobile site I know is possible, however not very useful for what i'm looking to make. The initial issues I can see, would be that the second app (the one you are redirecting to) needs to be downloaded to the mobile phone. Could the app you want to redirect be pre-installed in the first app? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "redirecting from one app to another" means.

Comment: Are you talking about redirecting between iOS and Android app?  or Two same platform apps?

Comment: I guess you are looking to create some kind of launcher or portal app? Yes you would probably have to install the second app separately. Say, you have the launcher installed, but not the second app, you could prompt the user to install the second app when they tap on the button and link them to where to download the second

Comment: Apologies, I should have made the question clearer. It would be across the same platform. so IOS to IOS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, if by redirecting what you meant is using an explicit intent. You can achieve this by adding this in the second app's manifest file

```
<activity
android:name=".SecondAppActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.xyz" />
</intent-filter>
```

and then launching an intent from first app like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.xyz");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Navneet. A little above my head but my dev should be able to make sense of this.

Comment: glad if it helped :)